# Как использовать FormData?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть похожая ссылка на файл: `file://.....`. Я пытаюсь загрузить этот файл на сервер используя этот код:

```
  var imageData = 'file://......';
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file-input', imageData);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "my_url");
  xhr.send(formData);
```

Но сервер говорит, что file-input не существует.

Что мне делать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

А вы случайно не можете получить imageData в Blob? Если да, то вот:

```
var $loadFile = $('<form method="post">');
var form = new FormData($loadFile[0]);
form.append('name', imageData, 'file.png');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: '/my_url/',
    data: form,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```